# C++ - How do I initialize a constructor of a separate class from the constructor of a class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to create a local (and private) instance of the class `deltaKinematics` in the class `geneticAlgorithm`

In the `geneticAlgorithm.h` file I have:

```
class DeltaKinematics; //class is defined in separate linked files

class GeneticAlgorithm {
  //private  
    DeltaKinematics deltaRobot;

public:

    GeneticAlgorithm(); //constructor

};
```

This is all fine, but when I go to declare the `GeneticAlgorithm` constructor, I can't work out how to construct the instance of `DeltaKinematics`

This is the `geneticAlgorithm.cpp` constructor:

```
GeneticAlgorithm::GeneticAlgorithm(){ //The error given on this line is "constructor for 'GeneticAlgorithm' must explicitly initialize the member 'deltaRobot' which does not have a default constructor"

    DeltaKinematics deltaRobot(100); //this clearly isn't doing the trick

    cout << "Genetic Algorithmic search class initiated \n";
}
```

How do I go about initializing that local instance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Member initializer list:

```
GeneticAlgorithm::GeneticAlgorithm() : deltaRobot(100) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Erik thats what I was after. Out of interest, what is the name of that language construct? I'm very new to c++ and still getting a grip on the jargon

Comment: It's a member initializer list, used to initialize base classes and member variables. Note that they will be called in the order member variables are *declared*, not in the order you specify them. You can initialize multiple members like this: `Foo::Foo() : BaseClass(0), MemVar(1), AnotherMemVar(2) {}`

Comment: what if that 100 isn't a constant but a variable the required some logic to be calculated before passed to the constructor

Comment: Use a static function to produce the value.

Answer (score 3):

```
GeneticAlgorithm::GeneticAlgorithm() : deltaRobot(100) {
    cout << "Genetic Algorithmic search class initiated \n";
}
```

Note the `:` after the constructor name: it is the beginning of the initialization sequence for the member data variables of the class. They appear as calls to their constructors, with the parameters you want to pass, and should be in the same order they're declared.

Comment: `:` starts member initializers, both base classes and member variables. And no, they don't need to be in order of declaration, but they will be *called* in order of declaration.

Comment: Well, it depends on compiler really, some compilers I've used insist on the order and give warnings if the order doesn't match.

Comment: There's no requirement that you place initializers in the order the member variables were declared. Gcc e.g. warns if you don't do it, but a compiler that considers incorrect order of initializers an *error* is simply incorrect.